# How can I trigger buffering of an Observable data stream when a certain value or condition is met?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I am using a Reactive Extensions Observable data stream tied to a COM port and I am displaying buffers from that data stream taken over a time interval.

This is my basic Rx code where byte data is returned in 25 millisecond chunks. I want to fire off the generation of the buffer the first time a particular threshold is hit, then do it again only after the previous buffer has been collected.

```
var o = serialData.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25))
                  .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
var mySerialObserver = o.Subscribe<IList<byte>>(SubscribeAction());
```

The serialData object is an IObservable of a continous stream of byte values coming from a USB COM port. The code for this was adapted from a Bart De Smet post:

[How to implement SerialPort parser with Rx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/rx/thread/5a12822d-92a6-4ff3-9a37-9bcce83dae0c)

Using the Rx Buffer(TimeSpan) method I can sample the serialData and display the buffer values on a graph (Using [DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) within my SubscribeAction method).

I would like to extend the functionality to behave like an Oscilloscope Trigger, this might involve invoking the Rx Buffer method at the point when a serialData value exceeds a given threshold value, but not collecting overlapping Buffers (this would be analogous to an Oscilloscope timebase triggering at a certain input voltage but not triggering again until the sweep is complete)

Please can someone give me some ideas of how this might be implemented?

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more about your problem/requirements. "threshold"? "collected"? etc...

Comment: I have an IObservable stream from a COM port - serialData which I obtained from a code sample from Bart de Smet

Comment: Sorry Enigmativity, I have put more detail in the primary post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffer would only release all your values until the buffer closes, which is not very useful for a real-time graph.
You'd have to split up the values into non-overlapping windows - which starts on a given trigger, and closes when the sweep condition is complete - a window for one complete sweep cycle.
Unfortunately, the window will still give us values when it starts, so we're going to have to skip all the values which come in before the trigger fires.

```
    static IObservable<IObservable<T>> TriggeredSweep<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source,
        Func<T, bool> triggerCondition,
        Func<T, bool> sweepEnd
        )
    {
        source = source.Publish().RefCount();
        return source.Window(() => source.Where(triggerCondition).Sample(source.Where(sweepEnd)))
                     .Select(s => s.SkipWhile(v => !triggerCondition(v)));

    }
```

The best way to test this out is on the very Oscilloscope model on which this is predicated:

```
        double period = 1000 / 0.5; //0.5 Hz
        int cycles = 4;             //cycles to display
        int quantization = 100;     //cycles to display            
        int amplitude = 10;         //signal peak            

        int range = quantization * cycles;    //full range 

        //Sine wave generator for n cycles
        //makes tuple of (t, sin(t))
        var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(period / range))
                               .Select(s => s % (range + 1))
                               .Select(s => Tuple.Create(s, amplitude * Math.Sin((double)s / ((double)range / (double)cycles) * 2 * Math.PI)));


        source.TriggeredSweep(
            value => value.Item2 > 5, //Trigger when Signal value > 5
            value => value.Item1 / quantization >= cycles //end sweep when all cycles are done
            )
              .Subscribe(window =>
              {
                  Console.Clear(); //Clear CRO Monitor

                  window.Subscribe(value =>
                  {
                      //Set (x, y)
                      Console.CursorLeft = (int)((double)value.Item1 / range * (Console.WindowWidth - 1));
                      Console.CursorTop = (int)((amplitude - value.Item2) / (2 * amplitude) * (Console.WindowHeight - 1));

                      //draw
                      Console.Write("x");
                  });
              });

        //prevent close
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
    xxx                   xxxx                   xxx                   xxxx
   xx  x                  x  x                  xx  x                  x  x
   x   x                 xx   x                 x   x                 xx   x
  xx    x                x    x                xx    x                x    x
  x     x               xx     x               x     x               xx     x
  x      x              x      x               x      x              x      x
  x      x              x      x              xx      x              x      x
         x              x       x             x       x              x       x
         x             x        x             x       x             x        x
          x            x        x             x        x            x        x
          x            x        xx           x         x            x        xx
          x           x          x           x         x           x          x
           x          x          x           x          x          x          x
           x          x          x           x          x          x          x           x
           x          x          x          x           x          x          x          x
           x          x           x         x           x          x           x         x
           xx        x            x         x           xx        x            x         x
            x        x            x        x             x        x            x        x
            x        x             x       x             x        x             x       x
            x       x              x       x             x       x              x       x
             x      x              x      xx              x      x              x      xx
             x      x               x     x               x      x               x     x
             x     xx               x     x               x     xx               x     x
              x    x                x    xx                x    x                x    xx
              x   xx                 x   x                 x   xx                 x   x
               x  x                  x  xx                  x  x                  x  xx
               xxxx                   xxx                   xxxx                   xxx
                x                      x                     x                      x
```

I hope this code might be useful for testing simple signal processing functions using Rx. :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is taking me some time to get my head around the Reactive Extensions and your example really helps. I am making the simplified assumption that all the data collected in one Buffer is evenly spaced over the time interval.

Comment: @CliveG No problem. Btw, you can mark this as the answer if you're okay with it.